# How to use multi-thread using BackgroundWorker class in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I read about using BackgroundWorker class to implement thread in Windows Form application. I have a small question: If I want 5 threads being running at the same time to handle specified tasks, I must create 5 BackgroundWorker controls or just need one?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking just `BackgroundWorker`, then you'd have to create 5 backgrounds workers.  If you simply want 5 threads, you can create those yourself.  The issue then becomes how to communicate progress and completion back to the UI thread.  With `BackgroundWorker`, you do that with `WorkerReportsProgress`/`ReportProgress` and the Completed event.  Now, you *could* certain just uses the `BackgroundWorker` `DoWork` handler to spawn the threads you want and manage communication of data from those threads back to the UI thread via `ReportProgress` and `Completed`.

For example:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   Thread thread1 = new Thread(ThreadOneEntry);
   thread1.Start();
   Thread thread2 = new Thread(ThreadTwoEntry);
   thread2.Start();
   Thread thread3 = new Thread(ThreadThreeEntry);
   thread3.Start();
   Thread thread4 = new Thread(ThreadFourEntry);
   thread4.Start();
   Thread thread5 = new Thread(ThreadFiveEntry);
   thread5.Start();

   thread1.Join();
   thread2.Join();
   thread3.Join();
   thread4.Join();
   thread5.Join();

   // do something to report results from threads1-5
}
```

This, of course, doesn't do anything with progress--that would be very application specific and anything I come up with is likely to be entirely different than what you would do and be of no help.  But, each thread could report progress back through the `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` method directly--you'd just have to give each thread the `BackgroundWorker` instances or a delegate to the `ReportProgress` method.

it's also not a terribly effective use of a thread for the background worker, it just goes into a wait state waiting for other threads, the `DoWork` event handler could just as easily do some of the work that one of the other thread entries would have...

I'd recommend using `Task<T>` instead of `Thread` if you are on .NET 3.5 or better and you want to perform background work that has results.  Plus, spinning up your own threads does no load-balancing.  Task through the TPL does its own load balancing...

Comment: Thank you very much.. My work is scraping from over 50 web links.. You think what should I choose to implement multithread?

Answer (score 0):

A BackgroundWorker is basically a single thread, so you would need multiple instances if you needed to run more than one thread.